# WinForms - Will there normally only be one instance of MainForm?

Tags: winforms

Will there normally only be one instance of MainForm?

I need to hold it as a static variable re [this issue I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526725/winforms-how-do-i-access-call-methods-in-ui-thread-from-a-separate-thread-witho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there would normally only be a single instance, unless you specifically create more instances of it in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have multiple instances of MainForm, if you declare a variable in the form as static (and not `ThreadStatic`), there will only be one copy of that variable.