# Implementing Progress Bar Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, progress-bar

I am trying to implement a progress bar in C# Winform. However I never implemented this feature.

My application sends number of emails and I wish to implement a progress bar that increments on every email sent. The number of emails differs from 16 - 50 approx.

Can this be implemented? and if yes how?

Any help please

Thanks for the answer, more help can be find on: [How to show progress bar in windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646575/how-to-show-progress-bar-in-windows-application)

Comment: What about the default standard `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar`? It should be enough in most cases **unless** you want some different look and feel.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the code logic of a progress bar? Or more on an overarching how-it-should-act-and-feel kind of thing?

Comment: There are thousands of examples if you try a simple search like `Winforms ProgressBar Examples`. You could also find a lot of questions like this in the Related column on the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the progress bars maximum value to the number of emails, for each email you send, increment the progress bar.

Something like this perhaps?

```
        private int emailLength;
        private ProgressBar ProgressBar1 = new ProgressBar();

         public void Main()
         {
            emailLength = 16;
            progressBar1.Maximum = emailLength;
            sendEmails();
         }
         public void sendEmails()
         {
             for (int i = 0; i <= emailLength; i++)
             {
                //Send Emails Here
                progressBar1.Increment();
             }
         }
```

Comment: +1 but I'd use emailCount not emailLength